# How can I set up a virtualenv that doesn't know about system packages?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

The title basically says it all.  I have `pip` and `virtualenv` set up on my computer and some packages are installed globally.  Is it possible to set up a virtual environment that doesn't know about the globally-installed packages?

For instance, `numpy` has already been installed with `pip install numpy` not in a `virtualenv`.

If I run

```
virtualenv testenv
cd testenv/
source bin/activate.csh
python  # which brings up a python prompt:
>>> import numpy
```

it knows what `numpy` is.  Is there anything I can do to make it forget about global installations when in a virtual environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create virtualenv with `--no-site-packages`:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages myevenv
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Interestingly, though, in `ipython`, it still knows what `numpy` is.  Do you know how to get ipython to forget in the `virtualenv`, too?

Comment: Use command `which ipython` to see where it is pulled from. Maybe IPython command doesn't come from virtualenv.

Comment: Ahh, that's great.  Yes, if I first run `pip install ipython` in the virtualenv and then `bin/ipython` to make sure not to use the system-installed version of IPython, then it doesn't know about numpy.